# Hide/Show Different dive based on contact form status

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a simple contact form. And when it is a success one div shows with a success message above the form and if there is an error another div shows that says error try agin. I have the code below and I have written where i want the code to go i just don't know what code to put.

Thanks for the reply. I tried what you suggested and it has not worked but here is my complete code for the page and the form. I would not mind using some ajax or JavaScript but I am not so good with these languages.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>My Math Contact Form</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--jQuery-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--placeholder fix-->
<script  src="js/placeholder.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('[placeholder]').placeholder();


});

</script>


<style type="text/css"> 
.number-field { width: 100px;display: inline; margin-left:5px;} 
</style> 

</head>

<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      $errors = array();

      if($_POST['name'] == "") {
         $errors[] = true;
      }
      if($_POST['email'] == "") {
         $errors[] = true;
      }
       if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
          $errors[] = true;
      }
      if($_POST['subject'] == "") {
         $errors[] = true;
      }
      if($_POST['comment'] == "") {
         $errors[] = true;
      }
      if ($_REQUEST['captcha_entered']!=$_SESSION['rand_code']) { 
         $errors[] = true;
      }
      if(count($errors) == 0) {
         $sendto = "luke@allthingsscene.co";//Your email goes here
         $name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
         $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
         $subject = $_POST['subject'];//You can change your subject here
         $comment = filter_var($_POST['comment'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

         $message = "<strong>$name</strong> has sent you a message by using the contact form:

        <p><strong>Name:</strong> <em>$name</em></p>

        <p><strong>Email:</strong> <em>$email</em></p>

        <p><strong>The subject:</strong> <em>$subject</em></p>

        <p><strong>Message:</strong> <em>$comment</em></p>";

        $headers = "From: $name <$email> \r\n";
        $headers .= "X-Mailer:PHP/\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version:1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

         if(mail($sendto, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
             $success = true;
         } else {
             $success = false;
         }
    } else {
       $success = false;

    }
  }

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     if($success == true) {
         echo "make error div show";
     }
     if($success == false) {
         echo "make error div show";
     }
 }

?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top:30px;" >
            <h1 class="text-center" style="color: #39b3d7;">
                    Welcome to my contact form
                </h1>

<!-- bootstrap form -->
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p><label for="name">Name </label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" id="name"></p>

   <p><label for="email">Email </label><input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="youremail@email.com" id="email"></p>

   <p><label for="subject">Subject </label><input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" id="subject"></p>

   <p><label for="comment">Message </label><textarea name="comment" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Drop a line"></textarea></p>

<?php echo '<img src="captcha.php" />'; ?><input name="captcha_entered" placeholder="Answer" class="form-control number-field" type="text" id="captcha_entered" size="5" maxlength="2" />
     <input type="hidden" name="captcha_total" id="captcha_total" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['rand_code']; ?>" />

   <p style="margin-top:20px;"><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Send Form"></p>
 </form>
<!-- bootstrap form END-->

 </div>
  </div>
   </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site.. it's not clear what your question is.. can you explain specifically which part of this you are having trouble with?  cheers

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any javascript right now to handle the form or is it straight php? Do you want to use any kind of javascript (ajax) to handle the form or do you want a traditional form submit?

If this is all your code, it looks like you are just using php.

You would want something like this:

```
<?php
$output = '';
if ( $_POST['submit'] )
{
    $errors = array();

    if($_POST['name'] == "") {
        $errors[] = true;
    }

    if($_POST['email'] == "") {
        $errors[] = true;
    }

    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $errors[] = true;
    }

    if($_POST['subject'] == "") {
        $errors[] = true;
    }

    if($_POST['comment'] == "") {
        $errors[] = true;
    }

    if ($_REQUEST['captcha_entered']!=$_SESSION['rand_code']) { 
        $errors[] = true;
    }

    if(count($errors) == 0) {
        $sendto = "luke@allthingsscene.co";//Your email goes here
        $name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];//You can change your subject here
        $comment = filter_var($_POST['comment'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        $message = "<strong>$name</strong> has sent you a message by using the contact form:

       <p><strong>Name:</strong> <em>$name</em></p>

       <p><strong>Email:</strong> <em>$email</em></p>

       <p><strong>The subject:</strong> <em>$subject</em></p>

       <p><strong>Message:</strong> <em>$comment</em></p>";

       $headers = "From: $name <$email> \r\n";
       $headers .= "X-Mailer:PHP/\r\n";
       $headers .= "MIME-Version:1.0\r\n";
       $headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

       if(mail($sendto, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
           $success = true;
       } else {
           $success = false;
       }
    } else {
        $success = false;
    }

    if ($success === true )
    {
        $output .= '<div id="success"><p>Your Success Message Here!</p></div>';
    }
    else
    {
        $output .= '<div id="fail"><p>Your Fail Message Here!</p>';
        $output .= '<ul>';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $errors.length; i++ )
        {
            $output .= '<li>'.$errors[i].'</li>';
        }
        $output .= '</ul>'; 
        $output .= '</div>';
    }

    echo $output;
}
else
{
 ?>

 <div class="container">
     <!-- all of your html "stuff" goes here -->
 </div>

<?php
}
```

Comment: I have posted my full page of code above with some additionall comments. So any Further help would be apritiated.

Comment: Cool. What I posted *should* get you going. The system will look for the $_POST['submit']. If it's there it will go through all the logic and render out the $output. (Will not show the form).